# Install Numpy for python3 in fedora 13

Tags: python, linux, installation

My university system has fedora 13. I installed python 3  (`sudo yum install python3`) and also installed numpy (`sudo yum install numpy`). Now numpy works only from default python (2.6) and does not work from python3. How can I use numpy package from python3?

Answer (score 0):

Try doing

```
sudo yum install numpy scipy python-matplotlib ipython python-pandas sympy python-nose
```

And as you are under Fedora 17

```
sudo pip install --upgrade ipython
```

Then you can just do (an example..)

```
>>from numpy  import *
>>nbr_values = 8192
>>n_iter = 100000
>>a = numpy.ones(nbr_values).astype(numpy.float32)
>>for i in range(n_iter):
...    a = numpy.sin(a)
```

Comment: I have Fedora 13 and above does not address my problem.